# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. For any $(a, b)$ containing $1$ there is $x\in (a, b)$ such that $f(x)=2$. Prove that $f(1)=2.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. For any $(a, b)$ containing $1$ there is $x\in (a, b)$ such that $f(x)=2$. Justify whether $f(1)=2$.

Assume $f(1) ≠ 2$, then we have two cases:

Case 1: $f(1) > 2$

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x)$ approaches $f(1)$ as $x$ approaches $1$. Then there exists an open interval $I$ containing $1$ such that for all $x \in I$, $f(x) > 2$.
But, this is a contradiction to the given property that for any open interval $I$ containing $1$, there exists a point $x \in I$ such that $f(x) = 2$. Therefore, $f(1)\ngtr 2$.

Similarly, we can show that $f(1) \nless 2$.

$\therefore f(1)=2.$

Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: You have to truncate your question with the word "whether" rather than an actual question because you tried to fit your question in the title. Don't do that. Ask your question clearly, not shortly. Put the full question in the body.

Comment: Your arguments are correct

Answer (score 4):

Another approach - for every $n$ consider $A_n=(1-1/n,1+1/n)$. Let $a_n\in A_n$ be such that $f(a_n)=2$. Note that $|a_n-1|<1/n$ for every $n$, that is $a_n\to 1$, therefore by continuity:
$$f(1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=2$$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct. More generally, by the same arguments: $X\ni x_0$ and $Y\ni y_0$ being topological spaces, if $Y$ is a [$T_1$-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space):

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map such that for any neighborhood $V$ of $x_0,$ $y_0\in f(V).$ Then, $f(x_0)=y_0.$

Comment: It should be sufficient for $Y$ to be $T_1$: then the hypothesis amounts to $x_0$ being in the closure of $f^{-1}(\{ y_0 \})$.

Comment: Thank you @DanielSchepler  for catching that misprint, I wrote $X$ instead of $Y.$ Corrected.